# Config not found: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf -- After setting up kubeadm worker node

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet

Following [this tutorial](https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/install-kubernetes-cluster-centos-8), I set up a worker node for my cluster. However, after running the `join` command and attempting `kubectl get node` to verify the node was connected, I am met with the following error

```
W0215 17:58:44.648813 3084402 loader.go:223] Config not found: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Checking for the existence of `admin.conf` in `/etc/kubernetes/` shows it does not exist. I have ensured that `$HOME/.kube/config` is also clear. Why is the join command not creating an admin.conf file?

Comment: Having similar error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**TLDR**

1. Run `join` with sudo
2. `mv /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf`

---

After some tinkering, I realized it was a combination of a permissions error and the correct file being generated with an incorrect name.

Instead of running `kubeadm join ...` naked, running with sudo allowed for the command to create files necessary in `/etc/kubernetes`

```
sudo kubeadm join <MASTER_IP:PORT> --token <TOKEN>     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash <HASH>
```

However this doesn't generate an `admin.conf`, but does create a `kubelet.conf`. I'm unsure why this happens, and couldn't find any documentation on this behavior, however running `kubectl` with the following parameter solved my issue

```
kubectl get nodes --kubeconfig /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
```

Rename `kubelet.conf` to `admin.conf` for your convenience at this point.